# Run multiple commands in same process in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line

How can I run multiple commands in the same process in Ruby? For example, I should be able to run the command `set TEMP=T` on Windows and when ran the command `echo %TEMP%` later get a result of `T`. The solution should be system independent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing shell command from ruby using the same shell process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175007/executing-shell-command-from-ruby-using-the-same-shell-process)

Answer (score 1):

Open a shell subprocess with popen, and save the handle. Run all your commands in this shell.
You can have it as a singleton, if it should be accessible from anywhere within the program.

Comment: I have no computer available at the moment, but you can find an example here:
https://coderwall.com/p/etxnsg/handling-sub-processes-in-ruby

Comment: It seems like running a thread, I need a way to keep the state of running a terminal (backticks run in a different PID for every call) .

Comment: Check the link I've attached. They aren't using backticks, they open a subprocess AND HOLD IT.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with the command prompt in Windows, how should I do that?